# Why Vibrio Cholera produce its toxins?

Tags: microbiology

I was wondering, why V. Cholera synthesize toxins which induce in humans diarrhea? I know that diarrhea is protective mechanism for humans, to get rid of bacteria. But why V. Cholera just stop producing it? What is its function in bacteria? In which bacterial metabolism it is involved?

Comment: Which of these questions do you most want to see answered? One of the questions you ask is very interesting to me, but I would not be interested in answering them all. Can you narrow this down to one (maybe two) question(s)? Thanks.

Comment: What is its function in bacteria?

Comment: Then may I  suggest you edit your question to basically just that? Because *that* is a *very* interesting question. Also, it would help if you included any research you've done to answer the question. Thanks! :)